# Aggregating data by month using SQL in metabase from redshift

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift, metabase, amazon-redshift-serverless

I hope you are doing well,

I am working on aggregating data by month,

Note: I am querying data from Redhsift using Metabase.

This is my query:

```
(SELECT 
     dataset.value AS value, 
     TO_CHAR(dataset.time ::date,'MM/YYYY') AS time, 
     COUNT(id) AS count
 FROM  
     dataset
 GROUP BY 
     dataset.value, TO_CHAR(dataset.time ::date,'MM/YYYY')
 ORDER BY 
     dataset.value ASC, TO_CHAR(dataset.time ::date,'MM/YYYY') ASC)

UNION ALL

(SELECT 
     dataset_2.value_2 AS x, 
     TO_CHAR(dataset_2.time ::date,'MM/YYYY') AS time, 
     COUNT(id) AS count
 FROM 
     dataset_2
 GROUP BY 
     dataset_2.value_2, TO_CHAR(dataset_2.time ::date,'MM/YYYY')
 ORDER BY 
     dataset_2.value_2in ASC, TO_CHAR(dataset_2.time ::date,'MM/YYYY') ASC)
```

However this query converts date into string. Hence the output is not in proper order. Eg: Jan 22, Jan 23, Feb 22, March 23 instead of Jan 22, Feb 22, March 22 and so on.

Below are the screenshot of two sample dataset.

[image]

[image]

Screenshot of the Desired Output:

[image]

Requesting your help improve the query so the date aggregated by month is in ascending order. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please share some sample data, and also the expected output. This would be helpful.

Comment: Hi @DataWrangler, I have added screenshots of the two datasets and the desired output. Let me know if that helps?. Unfortunately I don't see the option to upload files maybe because I am a new user here.

Comment: "However this query converts date into string" So why did you `TO_CHAR()` your date?

Comment: @Eric, I have tried To_date, Date part() none of them gave me aggregation by month and even if they do they don't show the date in Month/Year format in the output.

Comment: I  have also tried Date_Trunc('month', dataset.time) even though that aggregates the data but displays date as eg: 1 April, 2022 time instead of Month & year of the aggregated data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to just switch the `ORDER` clause

```sql
SELECT 
     D.value AS value, 
     TO_CHAR(D.time ::date,'MM/YYYY') AS time, 
     COUNT(event_id) AS count
 FROM  
     dategrouping D
 GROUP BY 
     D.value, TO_CHAR(D.time ::date,'MM/YYYY')
 ORDER BY 
     TO_CHAR(D.time ::date,'MM/YYYY') asc, D.value ASC
```

#### Result

| value | time | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5/5 - Better than before | 05/2022 | 2 |
| Skipped check-out | 05/2022 | 1 |
| 1/5 - Not too great | 06/2022 | 2 |
| 3/5 - About the same | 06/2022 | 1 |
| 5/5 - Better than before | 06/2022 | 2 |
| 3/5 - About the same | 07/2022 | 1 |
| 4/5 - Between About the same and Better than before | 07/2022 | 2 |
| 5/5 - Better than before | 07/2022 | 2 |
| Skipped check-out | 07/2022 | 1 |
| 4/5 - Between About the same and Better than before | 08/2022 | 2 |
| Skipped check-out | 08/2022 | 1 |
| 4/5 - Between About the same and Better than before | 09/2022 | 2 |
| 5/5 - Better than before | 09/2022 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

Thumbs up to be using metabase

I would recomend you to use the [`DATE_TRUNC()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATE_TRUNC.html) function instead of [`TO_CHAR()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_CHAR.html) so the date records will all be moved to the first day of each month and therefore still be stored as a date, which is able to be ordered.

Also, I would first use a CTE to union the date and aggregate it afterwards. The looks of the query would be something like this:

```
WITH data AS 
(
  SELECT 
      dataset.value AS value, 
      dataset.time AS time
  FROM  
      dataset
  UNION ALL
     (
     SELECT 
          dataset_2.value_2 AS value, 
          dataset_2.time AS time
     FROM 
          dataset_2
     )
 )

SELECT
    data.value,
    DATE_TRUNC('month',data.time) AS mth
FROM 
    data
GROUP BY 
    value,mth
ORDER BY 
    mth
```